# Main quest and levelling. Am I at the expected level?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm level 18 and I've just completed Alduin's wall. What level should I supposed to be at this point?

What is the expected level at the different stages of main quest?

Comment: I was about level 30 at Alduin's Wall. You're going too fast and are doomed to certain death. JK. You're fine.

Comment: I'm level 12 and i finished the storyline quests, oh well, the next month of my life will be devoted to finishing all the quests.

Comment: I'm so confused... See, when I play rpg video games, I like to have the distinct impression I'm god. No, really. I love being like a super high level right from the start and then just pwning everyone and cackling as I do it. I call it the "Pokemon" way of doing things because in that game, if you really wanted to, you could get your guy to lvl 100 and go on your merry way. Now is that possible in Skyrim? I powered up to level 10 and I went into Bleak Falls Barrow (like the 3rd quest or so) and GOT MY ASS KICKED. I had played the game prior and went in at level 3 and didn't have an issue at al

Comment: Not in Skyrim I'm afraid, as seen as dungeouns' difficulty adjusts based on your level when you step in...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not really how Skyrim works, you can really be any level. There are no expectations like that, the game scales with your level.

Comment: Agreed. I'm level 31 and haven't even finished the first quest after going to High Hrothgar.

Comment: Yeah, but when they designed the game, what _would_ be the average expected levels for players to be halfway through? Any guess?

Comment: @Emanuele There are no guesses to make. Your level does not really matter in respect to the main story line.

Comment: @Emanuele No, really, there's no expectation at all.  It's a long-standing tradition in Elder Scrolls games that the main questline can be done in any order with any other questline.  Enemies and loot will be scaled to your level.

Answer (score 2):

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonslayer

At the notes it says this,

Some higher-level characters may find it less than a challenge to kill Alduin, even on master difficulty. This can lead to the whole confrontation feeling a little anti-climactic. As such, it is suggested that players be sure to enter Sovngarde no later than level 35 if they value the story (Suggested level in the Official Guide is 24).

And that's for the last part of the main quest-line.

I'm level 15 now and am halfway through the Elder knowledge quest. This was all very do-able.

I don't think that the game scales with your level answer is correct since for example i can't get passed the kill the silverhand leader quest, and i tried like 10 times, but i keep getting insta killed by a guy. I've also read somewhere that for some quests to become available there's a level requirement.

Comment: Crap, I'm level 37 and what's Sovngarde?

Comment: @Coomie — Isn't that the land of the dead?  I'm not sure I like where this is going.  o.O

Answer (score -2):

i'm at the part where you gotta capture a dragon in dragonsreach (one of the last quests) at level 3 so, it doesnt matter what level you are, IMO if you are 15+ the main quest should be easier than a lower level. The higher level you are, the harder the monsters get. ^^ gl with skyrim!! awesome game :D